# Ajax connection check object no returning values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create some sort of ajax connection check object but for some reason i just cant get it to work :/

object:

```
function conn(data){

this.conn = false,

this.check = function(data){
   if(data){
      console.log("data: "+data)//Returns true
      this.conn = data;
      } else {
        this.callServer();
      }
},
this.callServer = function(){  
    $.get(ApiUrl("online"))
    .done(function(data){})
    .fail(function(data){})
    .always(function(data){var c = new conn();c.check(data)});
    }   
}
```

Usage:

```
var code = $(".login-form  input#pincode").val();
var con = new conn();
con.check();
    console.log("connection: "+ con.conn); // returns false
    code = code.match(/[0-9]/g);
    if (code === null || code.length !== 6) { 
        Alert("De code moet bestaan uit zes cijfers");
    } else {
        if(con.conn === true){
              //Do stuff
        }
```

The function 'ApiURL' is function that creates the url so dont mind that

Comment: You call con.check(); without data param

Comment: It has an if-statement on that.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the "data" when creating a new object with the using the object constructor. `var con = new conn();` need to be `var con = new conn(<data need to be inserted here>);` That is why it don't work I guess.

Comment: The data parameter is optional. When calling the 'check' method it checks for data...if not it does the ajax call wich does a callback to the 'check' method with the returned data